# python check value against binary tree, empty output

Tags: python, binary-tree, output

Been stuck on this problem now for a long time and its time to get some help. Almost everything works. It read the files and input the data and so on.. The program dont give me any output and something is wrong with the last if statments.. The three last rows is

```
root1.put(word1)
if root.exists(word1):
    print(word1, end = " ")
```

It puts in the value in the tree. and then it will check against the first tree if the value "word1" is already in that tree if that is true it will print out the word, if not go on. This program just give me an empty output. Is there any chance someone can see the problem? The other class file looks almost the same just without the 1's to all variables/para..

**Class file (root1)**

```
class BintreeEN:
    def __init__(self, data1):
        self.left1 = None 
        self.right1 = None 
        self.data1 = data1

    def put(self, data1):
        if data1 < self.data1:
            if self.left1 is None:
                self.left1 = BintreeEN(data1)
            else:
                self.left1.put(data1)
        else:
            if self.right1 is None:
                self.right1 = BintreeEN(data1)
            else:
                self.right1.put(data1)

    def write(self):
        if self.left1: 
            self.left1.write()
        print(self.data1) 
        if self.right1: 
            self.right1.write()

    def exists(self, data1):
        if data1 < self.data1:
            if self.left1 is None:
                return None, None
            return self.left1.exists(data1)
        elif data1 > self.data1:
            if self.right1 is None:
                return None, None
            return self.right1.exists(data1)
        else:
            return self.data1
```

**Program file**

```
#first tree
root = Bintree("root")
with open("word3.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    for row in file:
        word = row.strip()
        checklist = root.exists(word)
        if checklist == word:
            pass
        else:
            root.put(word)
#second tree
root1 = BintreeEN("root1")
with open('engelska.txt','r', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    for row in f:
        onerow = row.split()
        for rowz in onerow:
            word1 = rowz.strip()
            #HERE IT something thats wrong...
            if root1.exists(word1):
                pass
            else:
                root1.put(word1)
                if root.exists(word1): #Check if value is in the first tree
                    print(word1, end = " ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `exists()` method returns a True value, *always*. Your `.put()` is never called, as the first `if` is always true instead:

```
if root1.exists(word1):
    pass
```

Your `.exists()` method returns `(None, None)` in case the value does not exist in the tree, and a non-empty tuple is *always* True:

```
>>> if (None, None):
...     print 'A tuple is considered True if not empty'
... 
A tuple is considered True if not empty
```

Return simply *just* `None` instead, not a tuple:

```
def exists(self, data1):
    if data1 < self.data1:
        if self.left1 is None:
            return None
        return self.left1.exists(data1)
    elif data1 > self.data1:
        if self.right1 is None:
            return None
        return self.right1.exists(data1)
    else:
        return self.data1
```

or, by using the short-circuiting nature of `and` and the fact that `return` exits the function immediately:

```
def exists(self, data1):
    if data1 < self.data1:
        return self.left1 and self.left1.exists(data1)
    if data1 > self.data1:
        return self.right1 and self.right1.exists(data1)
    return self.data1
```

With this change your binary tree works fine:

```
>>> tree = BintreeEN('foo')
>>> tree.exists('foo')
'foo'
>>> tree.exists('bar')
>>> tree.put('bar')
>>> tree.exists('bar')
'bar'
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. But this still gives me an empty output.

Comment: @user2776294: Make sure you reloaded your modules correctly. With this change the binary tree works as expected for me.

Comment: Its strange.. Do you change anything else? I saw that your if statement is linked to root1 shouldnt it be linked to root the first tree to check the values there. Because before that if statement it checks the value on root1 tree and if it the value not exist in root1 will put it in the root1 tree and then it will check against the first tree "root" and if that value is in that list it will print it out else dont do anything

Comment: Its strange. I got this working now.. dont ask me how but it works now. Thanks alot for your post Martijn!